# form submit mvcintegrationtest framework testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm using the mvcintegrationtesting framework: 
https://github.com/chrisortman/MvcIntegrationTest

which is a based on:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/

The following model is posted but beforehand it is parsed into a dictionary.

```
[Serializable]
public class PatientViewModel
{
    public PatientViewModel()
    {
        Appointments = new EditableList<AppointmentListViewModel>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage")]
    [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage")]
    [Display(Name = "LastName", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PatientName", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage")]
    [Display(Name = "BirthDate", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Appointment", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public DateTime Appointment { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage")]
    [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage")]
    [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber2", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage")]
    [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ExtraInfo", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Duration", ResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public AddressViewModel AddressViewModel { get; set; }

    [UniqueItemsInList]
    public List<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<AppointmentListViewModel> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

This is the post method

```
SimulateBrowsingSession(session =>
{
    var queryString = string.Format("/Patient/Edit/{0}", patient.Id.ToString());
    var result = session.Get(queryString);

    var model = result.GetViewModel<PatientViewModel>();
    var postresult = session.Post(queryString, model);

});
```

The above results in no call what so ever to the controller. Hence my first question:
Why doesn't my breakpoint in the controller's edit post get hit. If i pass null intead of my model it does hit.

Next i tried the following:

```
var postresult = session.Post(queryString, new NameValueCollection
                                 {
                                     {"Id", patient.Id.ToString()},
                                     {"FirstName", patient.FirstName},
                                     {"LastName", patient.LastName}

                                 });
```

This results in a hit on the controllers edit post method, but only the Id is filled in, the firstname and lastname fields are null.

Second question: Why is this happening?
Third question: How do i solve Q1 and Q2?

EDIT: controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(PatientViewModel viewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {

                    var item = Map.This(viewModel).To<Patient>();
                    _patientService.Update(item);
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = item.Id });
                }
                catch
                {
                    AddSelectLists();
                    return View(viewModel);
                }
            }

            AddSelectLists();
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: could you share your controller/action code?

Comment: I've edited the code above